# Why does $\omega((I-E)T)=0$ here?

Tags: c-star-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading [Kadison-Ringrose-Vol2](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Fundamentals_of_the_Theory_of_Operator_A.html?id=h5bMkZTnowAC&redir_esc=y). The authors defined the *completely additive states* and their *supports* in **Definition 7.1.1**. And just after the definition they remarked the following:

> If $E$ is a support of a state $\omega$, then $\omega(I-E)=0.$

This is fine. Then they used **Proposition 4.5.1** to conclude the following:

> Since $I-E\ge 0$ and $\omega$ is a state then for any $T \in \mathscr{R}$,
> $$0=\omega(T(I-E))=\omega((I-E)T)$$

Here the first equality follows from **Proposition 4.5.1** by using the fact that for any state $\rho$ we have $\rho(B^*A)=0$ whenever $B\in \mathscr{R}$ and $A\in \mathscr{L}_\rho:=\{T\in \mathscr{R}~:~\rho(T^*T)=0\}$.

But how did the second equality follow? Why $\omega((I-E)T)=0$?
$T$ may not commutes with $I-E$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two arguments.

1. Because $\omega\geq0$, it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz:
   $$
   |\omega(B^*A)|≤\omega(A^*A)^{1/2}\omega(B^*B)^{1/2}.
   $$
   Then
   $$
   |\omega((I-E)T)|^2≤\omega((I-E)(I-E)^*)\omega(T^*T)=\omega(I-E)\omega(T^*T)=0.
   $$
2. The second way is to notice that $$\omega(T^*)=\overline{\omega(T)}
   $$
   for all $T$. Here if $S=S^*$ then $S=S^+-S^-$, and so $\omega(S)=\omega(S^+)-\omega(S^-)\in\mathbb R$. Then writing $T=A+i B$ with $A,B$ selfadjoint,
   $$
   \omega(T^*)=\omega(A-i B)=\omega(A)-i\omega(B)=\overline{\omega(A)+i\omega(B)}=\overline{\omega(A+i B)}=\overline{\omega(T)}.
   $$
   And now
   $$
   \omega((I-E)T)=\overline{\omega(T^*(I-E))}=0.
   $$